# How can I make a cryptogram encoder in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I've looked at other pages to see if there was a way to replace all occurrences of a character with another, and so far I've seen suggestions to use a regular expression in a replace method, as well as creating a hashmap to hold all the values to replace. After some finger magic I came up with this:

```
function encodeMe(input) {
    var chars = {
        "f" : "o",
        "o" : "b",
        "a" : "r"
    }
    var encodedMessage = input.replace(/[^ -~]/g, function(chr) {
        return (chr in chars) ? chars[chr] : "&#"+chr.charCodeAt(0)+";";
    });
    return encodedMessage;
}
```

Problem with this though is if I hand in "foo bar", it returns "foo bar" and not "obb brr".
I'm obviously doing something wrong but I can't figure out what. Could someone help me here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `-` in the character group at the end: `[^ ~-]`. Otherwise you are creating a *range*, and the expression means *"don't match any character that lies between  (space) and `~`"*, which includes letters as well.

http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I'm rather new to regular expressions, so I never would have caught that.

Comment: After checking out regular expression characters, I learned I can just use `/./g` instead of `/[^ ~-]/g` and it does the exact same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to not use regular expressions and just iterate over the string and build a new one:

```
function encodeMe(input) {
    var chars = {
        "f" : "o",
        "o" : "b",
        "a" : "r"
    }
    var newStringArray = [];
    for(var i=0; i < input.length; i++) {
        //if the current char is in the map, add the replacement
        //otherwise, add the char itself
        newStringArray.push(chars[input[i]] || input[i]);
    }
    return newStringArray.join("");
}
```